# How to calculate a comparative percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, percentile

We have 1002 seats in Head Start (all full) and 287 waiting for Head Start
We have 48 seats in Early Head Start (all full) and 256 waiting for Early Head Start

I'm trying to express to the directors the need for more seats in Early Head Start due to the higher wait list per seat available ratio). How could I say this in percentages or some other way? Something in the lines of "there is a xx% higher percentage of kids on the Early Head Start wait list (per seat) than there is in Head Start".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The percent of people wanting to be in Head Start is 128.6% of the allotted seats. ((1002+287)/1002) is another form of writing this
The percent of people wanting to be in Early Head Start is 633.3% of the allotted seats.
((256+48)/48) is another form of writing this

With these 2 percentages, you can also derive the amount of people who are waiting compared to those in, which are 28.6% and 533.3% respectively (the exact same numbers minus 100%0

From those first two percentages, we can tell that the ratio of entrants to spots from Early Head Start to Head Start is 4.92.

From the second two percentages, we can tell that the ratio of ***waiting*** entrants to spots from Early Head Start to Head Start is 18.65

These 2 statistics show different things, and are both viable measures of imbalance, and should each be used accordingly.